# Need advice on what the following port could be?

Tags: connector, identification, cables

I've tried searching for different USB port types to identify what this port might be but to no avail. The mini USB cable fits in here however all the pins don't match up.

Any idea what it could be?

[image: *COM port on POS device*]

Comment: What do you mean by "all the pins don't match up"? This really looks like a mini USB port for me.

Comment: The mini USB cable does not slot in well, it's a little loose. The cable and the port have 5 pins each but from the play it has I doubt any of them are actually making contact.

Comment: Follow the traces

Comment: I've seen some ports like this used as proprietary connectors on cameras, basically working as USB, but forcing to buy proprietary cables. They may also combine some other functions like video output. Don't know the name for it though.

Comment: That looks like a mini-USB type AB connector. If I remember correctly it was intended as the OTG dual-role host/device connector when mini-USB was the current standard.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that it is a:
MOLEX   47346-0001  USB Connector, Micro USB Type B, USB 2.0, Receptacle

As shown [here](http://www.newark.com/molex/47346-0001/micro-usb-2-0-type-b-receptacle/dp/17X0438?CMP=KNC-GUSA-GEN-SHOPPING-NEW-MOLEX&ad=81515568741&gclid=CJK6tNas48wCFZE0aQod6Z8MzQ)

[image]

Or possibly a:
MOLEX   56579-0519  MINI USB TYPE AB CONNECTOR, RECEPTACLE
Shown [here](http://www.newark.com/molex/56579-0519/mini-usb-type-ab-connector-receptacle/dp/20M7443?ost=MOLEX+%0956579-0519++MINI+USB+TYPE+AB+CONNECTOR%2C+RECEPTACLE&selectedCategoryId=&categoryNameResp=All%2BCategories&iscrfnonsku=false)

[image]
[image]